# Created pivot table from protected source data

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have data on a excel worksheet which is protected and I am trying to create a pivot table from this data. I have thoroughly searched about this on internet but didn't get anything.

Comment: I would copy the data from protected sheet to other worksheet and create a pivot table from that new worksheet as that sheet will not be protected.

Comment: Actually I am creating an automated excel application for my client so I can't ask him to copy the data and then create a pivot.

Comment: You can include the code to copy the sheet and create the pivot table. You can also copy and paste pivot table as values. Once task is over delete the temporary sheet and pivot table. All these will be in run time and not manual work.